Converting Rows of data into a single column, including IMAGES
I have found many solutions that pull rows of data into a single column of data, but I cannot figure out a solution that will also return images as part of the data.
Sample data is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q4qRgXSq6xXhddArPCoBIuOOupRvokUd0andADCNN0Q/edit?usp=sharing




You may try:
=let(Σ,B5:E7, reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(rows(Σ)),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,tocol(chooserows(Σ,c),1),))))



You make it look so easy! Thank you <3

If you don't need the blank spaces in between you can simply use TOCOL:
=TOCOL(B5:E7,1)



A non reduce approach:
=ifna(tocol(hstack(B5:E7,na()),1))

